# How to properly use VS BuildTools from VS code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I try to use VS Code to assemble a C# project. I installed VS Code and VS BuildTools. The problem is, the `tasks.json` generated by VS Code doesn't see a `msbuild` executable, since BuildTools didn't update the PATH. The "official" way of launching the utility is through the `LaunchDevCmd.bat` file, which is located in `BuildTools/Common7/Tools` folder. It sets up lots of stuff and env vars, and prepares the cmd, but VS Code, understandably, doesn't know anything about it.

What is the correct way to configure the VS Code to properly utilize the VS BuildTools?